# Manipulação de CSV no R

Tags: r, csv

Tenho vários arquivos com a extensão .csv, preciso ler todos, porém estou com um problema onde tenho a seguinte variedade de arquivo.

```
df1 -> Cabeçalho numérico antes do cabeçalho atual

1    2     3 
nome idade escolaridade
joao 10    6ano
Bia 20     faculdade

df 2 -> Cabeçalho sem numérico

nome    idade escolaridade
Joaquim 6     colégio
Andre   1    maternal

df 3 -> Separador #
```

Até o momento só fiz isso:

```
filenames = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
 if(is.empty(filenames)==FALSE)
for(c in 1:length(filenames)){

a<- read.table(filenames[c],,header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
}
```

Comment: `is.empty(filenames)==FALSE` não é boa ideia. Use `!is.empty(filenames)`.

Comment: qual a diferença ?

Comment: Não deve testar `variavel == TRUE` ou `variavel == FALSE` porque a variável **já é** `TRUE` ou `FALSE`. Basta `if(variavel)` no caso `TRUE` ou negar `if(!variavel)` no caso `FALSE`.

Comment: obgda, vou fazer essa mudança ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função data.table::fread é uma versão otimizada da read.table. A opção skip permite incluir uma string que marca o início do arquivo. A função também é bastante eficiente na detecção automática dos separadores, o que é bastante útil se seus arquivos seguirem diferentes padrões. Veja o exemplo:

```
library(data.table)

dfEx <- fread(
  input = '# um comentário marcado com "hashtag"
           data de criação: 12/10/2018
           1    2     3 
           nome idade escolaridade
           joao 10    6ano
           Bia 20     faculdade',
  skip = 'nome'  
)

> dfEx
   nome idade escolaridade
1: joao    10         6ano
2:  Bia    20    faculdade
```

O padrão do fread é gerar um objeto das classes data.table e data.frame; você pode mudar isso com a opção `data.table = FALSE`.

Para ler vários arquivos de uma vez, aplicar a função fread (ou read.table, etc) sobre a lista é mais eficiente do que usar um loop:

```
listaArquivos <- list.files(pattern = '.csv$')
# 0 $ indica para selecionar nomes que terminam com .csv

if( length(listaArquivos) ) listaDados <- lapply(listaArquivos, fread, skip = 'nome')
```

Isso vai gerar uma lista em que cada elemento é um data.table (ou data.frame). Você pode unir tudo usando a função data.table::rbindlist:

```
dados <- rbindlist(listaDados)
```